# How to isolate open applications, and ideally processes, in Ubuntu workspace?

Tags: users, workspaces, application-switcher, workspace-switcher, productivity

I combine work and study, so I need a separate set of tabs for each task. For example: for work it is chrome with work-related tabs, vscode, obsidian.md and others, and for study - chrome, but with others, overleaf, pycharm, todoist etc.

If you use built-in workspaces, the problem is that when you open the same application in one workspace, it opens a window of that application in another workspace, switching workspaces.

I would like tabs to be separate, and ideally -- and processes, so that multiple instances of, for example, telegram, spotify, and similar applications can be opened. One way to do this is to have separate users, but when you switch between them, one or the other user instance goes into hibernation or shuts down.

So my question is: how to isolate open applications or even processes, if it's possible, in Ubuntu workspace?

Comment: Do you have a question?   Your question text ends with a statement "*goes into hibernation or shuts down*" without any actual question!   Please make your question text clear (*details in the title may not be readable when the page is opened; not everyone uses desktop PCs with large screens!*).  Do you have a Ubuntu product/release in mind?  or are you asking what desktop will best achieve what you want?

Comment: In the general case, whether this is possible or not depends on each individual application. Some applications, like browsers, take care to identify the already-running process, and using it (along with state information like the logged-in user etc) even if you try to start a new process. Modern browsers typically have a command-line option to force the launcher to start a new process with a different user profile, but this is not typical for most other applications with this design.

Comment: @guiverc Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @tripleee Okay, if it's impossible to isolate all the processes of any app, then how to isolate opened tabs between workspaces? When I switch to another one, the panel doesn't change and stays with the same opened tabs.